# The Podfile does not contain any dependencies with xcode

Tags: objective-c, ruby, terminal, cocoapods

everybody, did you happen to encounter such an error while running the pod install command?

[Link to the error itself](https://pastebin.com/ELQ9PJFt)

Since I tried to reinstall ruby by this method already:

```
rvm install ruby-2.6.3
rvm use ruby-2.6.3
rvm --default use 2.6.3
```

And still, unsuccessfully.

and cocoapods are also unsuccessful anyway, there is simply no place to look for an answer.

This error flies away only when working with an Obj-c project (and quite ancient ones), because I am now looking at the cryptoPro library and the standard project is not launched there.

There are no such problems with new projects at the moment.

Comment: I remember when I was doing obective-c/swift, `xcode-select --install` helped me to solve some issues. Maybe it could help in that case

Comment: when typing this command, writes: 
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Run this command sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
after yours and unsuccessfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed an error. I will tell you what it was about me. I noticed this line in the bug:

```
untimeError - [Xcodeproj] Consistency issue: build setting ARCHS has multiple values: {"Debug"=>"$(ARCHS_UNIVERSAL_IPHONE_OS)", "Release"=>"$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)"}.
```

After that I got into the Targets -> Build Settings -> Architectures project itself.
Specify there $(ARCHS_STANDARD) for both cases and then everything worked!